# SQL move date schedule by account number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have payment schedule table and I want to move the date 1 payment prior for every account. It only cycles for 15  and (30 or 28 or 29 for february).

```
accountno | inst_no  | date(datetime) | amount
0001      |    1     | 8-15-2017      | 100
0001      |    2     | 8-30-2017      | 100
0001      |    3     | 9-15-2017      | 100
---------------------------------------------
0002      |    1     | 6-15-2017      | 100
0002      |    2     | 6-30-2017      | 100
0002      |    3     | 7-15-2017      | 100
--------------------------------------------
0003      |    1     | 8-15-2017      | 100
0003      |    2     | 8-30-2017      | 100
```

Result

```
accountno | inst_no  | date(datetime) | amount
0001      |    1     | 8-30-2017      | 100
0001      |    2     | 9-15-2017      | 100
0001      |    3     | 9-30-2017      | 100
---------------------------------------------
0002      |    1     | 6-30-2017      | 100
0002      |    2     | 7-15-2017      | 100
0002      |    3     | 7-30-2017      | 100
--------------------------------------------
0003      |    1     | 8-30-2017      | 100
0003      |    2     | 9-15-2017      | 100
```

Can this be done on query?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What do you mean by "date 1"?

Comment: I mean move the schedule 1 date prior. like if it is 8-15-2017 now then it should be 8-30-2017 after I execute the query

Comment: So you mentioned result is wrong !!! 0001      |    1     |`8-15-2017`      | 100     ====>>>     0001      |    1     | `8-30-2017`      | 100

Comment: and what value is expected if the date is 2-15-2017?

Comment: @AliAdlavaran what you mean is wrong? I see no difference on what you wrote and the one i posted.

Comment: @RadimBača please see my edit for the month of february.

Comment: I'm going to delete my answer and flag the question unclear ... OR you may edit your question and say what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this? You can easily rewrite into `SELECT`.

```
UPDATE PaymentScheduleTable 
SET d = CASE WHEN DAY(d) = 15 
             THEN 
               CASE WHEN MONTH(d) = 2
                    THEN DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,d)+1,0)) -- last day of month
                    ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 15, d) 
               END 
               ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 15, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,d)+1,0)))
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified Radim's answer and came up with this solution.

```
(CASE 
                 WHEN DAY(date) = 15 
                 THEN case when MONTH(date) = 2 then EOMONTH(date) else  DATEADD(DAY, 15, date)  end                                                              
                 ELSE  DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(day,-15,date))    
               END )
```

Thanks for your help. Sorry if my question is unclear.